# Changing spring property value dynamically on from DB after server startup

Tags: java, spring

I have configured to load all my properties from DB.

```xml
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="beanName" value="databaseConfiguration"/>
</bean>

<bean id="commonsConfigurationFactoryBean"   class="org.springmodules.commons.configuration.CommonsConfigurationFactoryBean">
    <constructor-arg ref="databaseConfiguration" />
</bean>

<bean id="autobotDataSource" class="com.commons.dao.AdminDataSource"/>

<bean id="databaseConfiguration" class="org.apache.commons.configuration.DatabaseConfiguration">
    <constructor-arg type="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="autobotDataSource" />
    <constructor-arg name="table" value="testdb.properties" /><!-- configuration table name -->
    <constructor-arg name="keyColumn" value="prop_key" /><!-- key column -->
    <constructor-arg name="valueColumn" value="key_value" /><!-- value column -->
</bean>
```

And I have imported that in my properties.

I am able to get the value in bean using `@Value` annotation. But if I update a value in DB it is not getting reflected in my application with out restart is there a way to dynamically update the value.

Comment: Don't load them using this approach.

Comment: why? which is a better approach then?